# Why is charge constant in series connections?

Tags: charge, capacitance

Why does each capacitor in a series connection hold the same charge? I understand that voltages and capacitances across capacitor plate pairs in series vary, but why is it a necessity that charge be constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This site from the University of Texas](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/302l/lectures/node46.html) provides a good explanation, I think.

Basically, when you have two capacitors connected in series, say $C_1$ and $C_2$, then the total charge in the middle wiring connecting the two components must remain constant, as it cannot escape anywhere.

Any charge accumulation in in $C_1$'s outer plate creates a virtual charge accumulation in its inner plate, but the total charge in the middle wiring must remain constant, so there will be an equal, but opposite virtual charge created at $C_2$'s inner plate. The virtual charge on $C_2$ will cause actual charge to accumulate on its exterior plate, and so the total charge in $C_1$ will be equal to the total charge in $C_2$.

You can think of it as the boundary condition between the capacitors forcing the charge fluctuations to propagate through the structure, in a sense.

Answer (score 2):

Think of two capacitors in series.

[image]

- If electrons e.g. move to the left plate of capacitor $C_2$, that plate gains some negative net charge, let's call it $-Q$.
- The negative charge on the left plate repels like-signed charge on the right plate (electrons are repelled from the right plate and pushed away to the right). This right plate of $C_2$ thus gets a net *positive* charge of the same amount, $+Q$.
- The electrons (the amount of negative charge $-Q$) is "pushed" as far right as possible; that is, to the left plate of $C_1$. This plate therefor gets a net *negative* charge of $-Q$.
- As before, a net charge of $+Q$ is now induced on the right plate of $C_1$.

It has to be balanced in this way. If one capacitor plate has a different charge magnitude than it's counterpart, then more/less charge will be repelled, and equilibrium has not yet been reached. Only equal (but oppositely signed) charge on to opposing plates will be in equilibrium.

And from right plate of $C_2$ to left plate of $C_1$, the repelled electrons, whose absense cause the charge $+Q$ on the right plate of $C_2$, are themselves moved to the left plate of $C_1$, which therefor necessarily must obtain the same amount of charge, but with opposite sign.

Answer (score 0):

Because any charge surplus on the one capacitor can only come from the other capacitor. Hence, neither can acquire or lose a charge without the other changing by exactly the same amount.